# Debugging : is it possible to print all local variable (with values) of C code without going into each stack frame?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, coredump

I am trying to explore `gdb`, `objdump`, `valgrind` and `nm` tools for debugging purpose in linux.

I am able to print local variables using `info locals` in GDB but I need to go into current stack frame to print local variables.

Is there any way to print all the local and global variables (with values) used in a C code (maybe from a coredump if program is crashed) without going into particular stack frame?

Comment: "info variables"----> Print the names and data types of all variables that are declared outside of functions (i.e. excluding local variables).but you won't get values. "info locals"---> Print the local variables of the selected frame, each on a separate line. These are all variables (declared either static or automatic) accessible at the point of execution of the selected frame.Again you won't get values.It's just list

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, in `gdb` you can show the local variables for the current frame with `info locals`. If your restriction is that you don't want to manually go into each frame, then you can use a simple `gdb` script that does that for you. For example:

```
define locals-up
  set $n    = ($arg0)
  set $upto = $n
  while $upto > 0
    info locals
    up-silently 1                                                                
    set $upto = $upto - 1
  end
  down-silently $n
end
document locals-up
  locals-up <n>: Lists local variables of n frames
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Well no, since you have to analyze the stack in order to figure out which local variables even exist.

If you have a a function:

```
static int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
  const int ab = a + b;
  const int bc = b + c;

  return ab * bc;
}
```

you can't talk about "the local variables of `foo()`" unless you have a stack frame that indicates that `foo()` is running. Otherwise, the local variables won't exist: they're allocated on the stack as the function is entered, after all.

Of course, there could be a "clever" command to walk up the stack from a given breakpoint's frame and print all encountered functions' local variables, but that doesn't sound like what you're after.

Comment: as you said local variables are allocated on the stack as function is entered. so is there not a way to save the local variable with values(at the time of execution of function) in a file. this can be useful for debugging.

Comment: I am not aware of any debugger that can do that 'automatically'.  Could be messy, especially if the function is entered from multiple threads.